NameError: name '_LanguageModel' is not defined
I am trying to initialize vertexai llm in langchain library.
from langchain_community.llms.vertexai import VertexAI
    
llm = VertexAI(
        max_output_tokens=1024,
        temperature=0.2,
        top_p=0.8,
        top_k=40,
        verbose=True,
    )

I get the following error with this.

ConfigError: field "client" not yet prepared so the type is still a
ForwardRef, you might need to call VertexAI.update_forward_refs().

And when I called this function I got.

NameError: name '_LanguageModel' is not defined

I also went through the source code and tried importing _LanguageModel manually just before the code but it's not working.
How can I resolve this?

Hi @vivek, It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCPsupport case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker  describing your issue.

This is langchain error so GCP support won't be relevant here.

So, first, a few things:

Your question does not include all the necessary information. By installing langchain-community (via pip), I was able to replicate the error, and here is the full stacktrace you should have provided:
$ python
Python 3.11.9 (main, Apr 10 2024, 13:16:36) [GCC 13.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from langchain_community.llms.vertexai import VertexAI
>>> VertexAI.update_forward_refs()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 814, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.update_forward_refs
  File "pydantic/typing.py", line 556, in pydantic.typing.update_model_forward_refs
 equivalently.
  File "pydantic/typing.py", line 522, in pydantic.typing.update_field_forward_refs

  File "pydantic/typing.py", line 68, in pydantic.typing.evaluate_forwardref
 'Hashable',
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/typing.py", line 910, in _evaluate
 self.__forward_value__ = _eval_type(
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/typing.py", line 395, in _eval_type
 return t._evaluate(globalns, localns, recursive_guard)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/typing.py", line 905, in _evaluate
 eval(self.__forward_code__, globalns, localns),
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name '_LanguageModel' is not defined


From the stack trace, we can see that, clearly, the error has nothing to do with the import, and everything to do with the pydantic library.

As one can see in the file langchain_community/llms/vertexai.py, line 32, the _LanguageModel import is in an if TYPE_CHECKING: block. And then, on line 126, you can read client: "_LanguageModel" = None  #: :meta private:. Here, the "type annotation [is] enclosed in quotes, making it a “forward reference”, to hide the [_LanguageModel] reference from the interpreter runtime." (directly quoting the docs.python.org paragraph about TYPE_CHECKING).

langchain_community/llms/vertexai.py, line 126 is the line that caused the first error you encountered. As you can see, the class _VertexAICommon has several class member variables, and the client and client_preview ones have type hints with the aforementioned "forward reference" technique. They are actually the only ones with "forward reference" hints (AKA "postponed annotations" in pydantic terms).

Those postponed annotations do not get resolved during model creation, and you need to call update_forward_refs on them to update the references, so that they resolve.

However, the _LanguageModel class is only imported (in the langchain_community/llms/vertexai.py file) from the language_models/_language_models file in the vertexai module during static type checking. It isn't imported at runtime.
To quote the docs.python.org paragraph about TYPE_CHECKING once more:

[TYPE_CHECKING is a] special constant that is assumed to be True by 3rd party static type checkers. It is False at runtime.


Therefore, you need to import the _LanguageModel (you did), and update any references to it in the _VertexAICommon class (seen to you as its VertexAI implementation name, which inherits both _VertexAICommon and BaseLLM). But _LanguageModel does not exist in its context at runtime, so you need to expose it. There is even a warning about this in the pydantic doc:

To resolve strings (type names) into annotations (types), pydantic needs a namespace dict in which to perform the lookup. For this it uses module.__dict__, just like get_type_hints. This means pydantic may not play well with types not defined in the global scope of a module.


To solve your problem, you therefore need to inform pydantic to update the references named _LanguageModel with the _LanguageModel class, using the aforementioned dict parameters for the update_forward_refs function.


TL;DR: This works:
$ python
Python 3.11.9 (main, Apr 10 2024, 13:16:36) [GCC 13.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from langchain_community.llms.vertexai import VertexAI
>>> from vertexai.language_models._language_models import _LanguageModel as differentNameToMakeItObvious
>>> VertexAI.update_forward_refs(_LanguageModel=differentNameToMakeItObvious)

N.B.: When instantiating the VertexAI from langchain_community, the following warning is displayed:

The class VertexAI was deprecated in LangChain 0.0.12 and will be removed in 0.3.0. An updated version of the class exists in the langchain-google-vertexai package and should be used instead. To use it run pip install -U langchain-google-vertexai and import as from langchain_google_vertexai import VertexAI.

From what I could tell, langchain_google_vertexai does not suffer from the same problem regarding the "forward references".

Try this:
from langchain.llms import VertexAI


The _import_vertex() function (called from __getattr__) in the langchain/llms/__init__.py file literally runs from langchain_community.llms.vertexai import VertexAI. I don't see how this would help...
